# RESTful route structure of 3 related categories in Express/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, express

I am a noob designing an API for an ecommerce site and I need to work out my restful route structure.  We are basically using Node and React along with Express + GraphQL.  I was wondering if someone could shine a light on the structure?

Here is what we Have:

1. It is a fashion store that has many products: skirts, blouses, tops, shirts, dresses, etc. You know the drill.
2. Each of these items will be in categories like this: 
   /dresses  (GET all dresses)
   /dresses/:id (GET a particular dress)

/skirts (GET all skirts)
/skirts/:id (GET a particular skirt)

3. In addition to all the products and the categories of products, at the top level we have DESIGNERS.

So, you would have a designer who has many categories, and each category has many products.  Make sense?

I am puzzling over how to nest the express routes.

I want to do these things....

1. Get all designers
2. Get all categories a designer has a product in
3. Get all products a designer has in the store
4. Get an individual (:id) of a product a designer has.

by the same token I also want to ...

1. Get all categories.
2. Get all products in a category
3. Get and individual product (:id) in a category.

So we have a parent route (designers)
and then two child routes (I think) within designers which
are /categories, /categories/:id, and /categories/products, and /categories/products/:id

Could someone get me a code hint on creating the routes in express?  I am wanting to create a JSON structure to render with this

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially asking how to build out an entire REST framework for a backend, which is quite a lengthy thing to answer :)

I'd suggest you start by designing the structure of the JSON for all these objects. Here's a handy site that allows you to visually see the layout of the JSON: https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Once you've done that for all the objects you've mentioned, here's a good tutorial on how to build basic node.js endpoints: https://medium.com/@purposenigeria/build-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-express-js-d7e59c7a3dfb